# Unable to get aside class to respond to CSS in WordPress style.css

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am creating my website on WordPress and am trying with no success to style the sidebar. The HTML shows `<aside class="sidebar sidebar-primary widget-area" [etc.]>`.

For the life of me, I cannot get a border radius on this class. I've tried using

```
.sidebar .sidebar-primary .widget-area { border-radius: 5px; }
```

with no avail. I've tried nesting it under its parent div but that didn't work either.

I got the main content area to respond, but this one seems to be a bigger pain. Is there something I'm missing for aside classes? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: p.s Please accept an answer when you have had chance to take a look :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution:**

Since the HTML code has multiple classes, you can target it with `Multiple class selector`:

```
.sidebar.sidebar-primary.widget-area {
   border-radius: 5px;
}
```

**Problem:**

Remember that you were trying to use `Descendant selector`

Your code `.sidebar .sidebar-primary .widget-area`  would have worked for:

```
<aside class="sidebar">
   <div class="sidebar-primary"> 
      <div class="widget-area"> 
         // Contents of widget area
      </div>
   </div>
</aside>
```

**Edit:**

After you posted your live demo, it seems you wanted to add border-radius to each individual widget. My suggested solution will not work again for that. It targets the whole widget area. Below is the CSS rule you are looking for:

```
.sidebar .widget { border-radius: 5px; }
```

Comment: Thank you, @Manoj. I used the multiple class selector you mentioned, and attempted using the above in addition to adding aside in front, but I cannot seem to get this to render. Here is the site (perhaps this will help?):
http://steffanylynn.com/shop/

Comment: You will need to target with `.sidebar .widget { border-radius: 5px; }` http://prntscr.com/7tcgjr

Comment: Thank you!! If possible, can you tell me how you figured that out? I only found widget-area as a class and never widget on its own.

Comment: Check this: http://i.imgur.com/haMcR1R.jpg The widget is highlighted with the padding(violet area) around it which includes the border.

Answer (score 1):

```
.sidebar .sidebar-primary .widget-area { border-radius: 5px; }
```

means you are are targeting a class of .widget-area that exists under .sidebar-primary that exists under .sidebar. In order to achieve the effect you actually want

```
.sidebar.sidebar-primary.widget-area { broder-radius: 5px; }
```

which means you are targeting a class of sidebar that also has classes of .sidebar-primary and widget-area

Answer (score 1):

```
.sidebar.sidebar-primary.widget-area { border-radius: 5px; }
```

...is what you want (note the lack of spaces between the class selectors).

Depending on your specificity requirements, you might only need:

```
.sidebar-primary.widget-area { border-radius: 5px; }
```

Or:

```
.widget-area { border-radius: 5px; }
```

You only nest selectors when your HTML is nested. Your HTML isn't nested, you just have multiple classes on the same DOM node :)

Nested HTML would look like:

```
<aside class="sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar-primary">
        <div class="widget-area">
        ...
        </div>
    </div>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to above answers, you can target it like

```
aside.sidebar-primary {   // or aside.widget-area depending on your needs
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -o-border-radius: 5px;
    -ms-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

The first four lines are vendor-prefixed properties offered by rendering engines (-webkit for Chrome, Safari; -moz for Firefox, -o for Opera, -ms for Internet Explorer) to avoid cross-browser inconsistencies.